# Boostrap capacitor charge path

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving, bootstrap

I want to make a bootstrapped high side switch, something like this:

[image]

(source [SLUA618A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slua618a/slua618a.pdf), interesting for many things, by the way)

The *negative voltage transient* label is not pertinent to the question, I simply chose the best picture to illustrate the question. Also my switch is polarity protected so there are two main MOSFETs back-to-back with the source in common.

The bootstrap idea is to charge the Cbst while the output is low, thru the diode an then use the charge to turn on the gate: as the channel open the source goes up to almost vin and the drive voltage follows up to almost Vin+Vdrv (less one diode). Occasionally the driver is brought down to recharge the capacitor (since it needs to power up the gate driver chip final stage).

The question is this: I've always used it in an half bridge configuration (sync rectifier or H-bridge). When the top driver goes down the low driver enables so the bootstrap cap can charge: Vdrv, Dbst, Cbst, Lower FET.

In a top only configuration like that in figure, the ground path is thru the load (the LC in the picture example) or is there some occult return path I'm not seeing?

Should I provide a small FET in the low side just to ensure a stable recharge?

Direct drive with Vin+10V is not feasible due to Vgs limitations, so I choose a bootstrap drive. Transformer drive could be difficult due to the 99.9% duty cycle (also: not cheap). Photovoltaic only give microamps of gate (and these MOSFETS are *huge*). Any other idea?

Comment: *In a top only configuration like that in figure, the ground path is thru the load (the LC in the picture example) or is there some occult return path I'm not seeing?* That is correct, you have to have a load that will allow sufficient current flow when the external MOSFET is off. So when the load is a resistor, motor or lightbulb that should work OK, if there is some electronic circuit, that might not work properly. Then indeed an extra NMOS might be needed to pull the output low, as the current could be a short, large pule, you might still need a beefy MOSFET (not a small one).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I think you may be missing something here; when the MOSFET turns off, the inductor keeps current flowing into the capacitor to pass energy. That causes the diode just before the inductor to become forward biased and negative 0.6 volts is produced on the left side of the inductor. This then replenishes the boot capacitor.

Comment: @Andyaka I agree with you that, once the system is working, it can keep going. However, I was thinking of startup, the boostrap cap is empty and the load doesn't want to conduct (much) current. You could end up in a situation where the bootstrap cap cannot get a proper charge so how would the system then start? So my point: the behavior of the load could prevent startup.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie at start up when the capacitor or load are holding the output voltage close to 0 volts, the MOSFET can only really work as a source follower and therefore it can be a bleak start from cold, but, it will get there if the load is not over demanding.

Comment: Uhm then the picture only works because of the inductor (which my load isn't:D) I didn't consider it.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you see why it works straight out of the box: -

[image]

- Fig. 1 shows the state in which the switching element Q1 is turned on.
- When Q1 is turned on, current passes from the input pin VIN to the coil L to charge the output smoothing capacitor CO, and the output current IO is supplied.
- The current flowing in the coil L at this time generates a magnetic field, and electrical energy is converted into magnetic energy and accumulated.
- Fig. 2 illustrates the state in which the switching element Q1 is turned off.
  When Q1 is turned off, the diode D1 turns on, and energy accumulated in L is discharged to the output.

Picture and text from [this site](https://techweb.rohm.com/knowledge/dcdc/dcdc_pwm/dcdc_pwm02/2200).

> *or is there some occult return path I'm not seeing?*

**Short story**: each time the MOSFET switches to an open circuit state, diode D1 gets forward biased by the action of the inductor trying to maintain its current. This inevitably means that the cathode of D1 falls immediately to about 0.6 volts below ground for a short period of time allowing the inductor to pass it's stored energy to the capacitor and load. This will charge the bootstrap capacitor correctly.

Comment: Can someone explain why this answer has been downvoted (it's the 3rd time today this has happened).

Comment: the answer appears to be correct

Comment: Yes, with the inductor it works fine. However I don't have it since my load is… ugly (an electrochemical cell with 50-100A of load). Time for an auxiliary MOSFET

Comment: Well, I can only answer based on information provided in the question. Why not fit a small value inductor? @LorenzoMarcantonio

Comment: A 100A small inductor would be probably larger than a relatively small MOSFET in the low side (it would have to try to discharge the load so it's not a negligible current). Or maybe just wiring inductance parasitics could be enough, I need to study on what's better.

Comment: You cannot use a MOSFET to do what you want with your cell directly connected to the output. Think about the discharge current into that MOSFET because it will short your cell out. Fire and smoke and not recommended.

Comment: The cell is a load, not a generator. I would 'discharge' the residual charge, however, that's not a trivial amount of power, I agree with that.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio are we done with this Q and A now?